# Jquery deleting last tr until 1 is left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the current code in my view:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#add_instruction").click(function(){
        $("#instructions").append("<tr><td></td><td><input type='text' name='recipe_instruction[]' size='60'/></td></tr>");
    });

    $("#remove_instruction").click(function(){
        var counter = $("#instructions").children("tr").length;
        if(counter>1){
        $("#instructions tr:last").remove();}
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<th colspan='2'>Recipe Details</th>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='recipe_name'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description:</td>
<td><textarea cols='50' rows='5'name='recipe_description'></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id='instructions'>
<th colspan='2'>Recipe Instructions</th>
<tr>
<td><input type='button' id='add_instruction' value='Add more instruction' /></td>
<td><input type='button' id='remove_instruction' value='remove last instruction'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type='text' name='recipe_instruction[]' size='60'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Adding of tr is fine, but deletion is not working. Plus, am i doing it wrong? in deletion, i think its because of my if statement of counter. If i dont add an if statement that tracks if only 1 tr is left, the remove function would ruin the table by removing all tr if there is none left. How should i do this?

EDIT:

```
<table>
<th colspan='2'>Recipe Details</th>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='recipe_name'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description:</td>
<td><textarea cols='50' rows='5'name='recipe_description'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr id='instructions'>
<td><input type='button' id='add_instruction' value=' Add more instruction  ' /></br>
<input type='button' id='remove_instruction' value='Remove last instruction'/></td>

<td id='instruction'><input type='text' name='recipe_instruction[]' size='60'/></br></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way of deleting until 1  is left?

Comment: `<th>` element should be in `<tr>`.

Comment: Does it make any significant difference?

Comment: This is invalid markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
$("#remove_instruction").click(function () {
    var $trs = $("#instructions tr");
    if ($trs.length > 3) {
        $trs.last().remove();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Vp9MU/)

- table.children('tr'), won't work because the browser add a `tbody` between the table and the trs
- You have 2 static rows you need those 2 + 1
- also it is best to cache the `tr` result and use it inside the `if` condition

Comment: Why is it 3? not 1? hmm.

Comment: AHh, nvm my question, i just realized, i used the whole table.

Comment: but then 2 also does the trick, why 3? i mean, i only created 1 tr and another tr as initial.

so 2 is enough right

Comment: it depends on whether you want to remove all the input elements from the table... try it.. and decide what you want to go with

Comment: Would changing TR:last to TD:last work if i appended <td></td> inside a tr id='instructions' ?

Comment: Could you look at the EDIT i will make, i changed my table.

Is there any way to deleting until last <input type='text'>?

Comment: @user3432132 can you update the fiddle to reflect the case and share the updated url

Comment: I posted the edit, Idk if its my net, but the fiddle just seems to be in endless loading.

Comment: what change did you make to the add method

Comment: <input type='text' name='recipe_instruction[]' size='60'/></br>

Just that, coz i appended inside the TD.

Comment: @user3432132 one option you could use is to use a tbody with the id `instruction` as given in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Vp9MU/4/

Comment: Ill probably just revert to the old one with separated table.

Although, ill accept your answer since you answered my previous one, 

still ill keep the new one available.

Comment: @ArunPJohny is this possible?  $("#instructions text:last").remove();

selecting the last input type='text' inside td id='instructions'

Comment: you want to delete the `tr` or the `input` element?

Comment: @user3432132 it will be great if you can make the jsfiddle work in your system so that the cases can be recreated... which browser are you using

Comment: the input element inside the td. since i am appending inside the td input elements.

Comment: so you are appending all the input elements to the td with id `instructions`

Comment: @user3432132 `$("#instructions input:last").prev('br').addBack().remove();`

Comment: Last question, on the find().length. same purpose i want to leave one behind.

Comment: @ArunPJohny would it be possible to delete 3 input type='text' at the same time?

Comment: @user3432132 yes it is possible... how do you decide which 3

Comment: @ArunPJohny

All 3 input types text if i appended 3 side by side like <input type='text' name='name[]'/><input type='text' name='age[]'/><input type='text' name='children[]'/></br>

Comment: I put them in a <p></p> so they would all be deleted same time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should keep it easy:

```
$("#remove_instruction").click(function() {
    $('#instructions tr:has([name="recipe_instruction[]"]):last').remove();
});
```

This will remove last `<tr>` in `#instructions` which contains element with attribute `name` equal to `recipe_instruction[]`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bCpuX/

Answer (score 0):

`$('#instructions').children('tr').length` is always `0`. That's because browsers add an implicit `<tbody>` between them, and `$.children()` only finds immediate children. Therefore use the more generic `.find()`:

```
$("#remove_instruction").click(function(){
  var counter = $("#instructions").find("tr").length;
  if(counter>1){
    $("#instructions tr:last").remove();
  }
});
```

(Just note, that this will be wrong, when you have nested tables.)